# Why can't I use 2 JSX tags inside the render method?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm have a error saying that jsx should be inside a enclosing tag <>..., but only when I put 2 jsx lines (in this case: Text and Image). What I'm doing wrong?

I'm a very beginner

```
export default class Bananas extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    return (
      <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
      <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (11:6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each react component must return markup encapsulated in a single parent:

```
return (
 <div>
  <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
  <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
 </div>
);
```

or fragment style

```
return (
 <>
  <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
  <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
 </>
);
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your elements with `<ReactFragment />`, or any top level element (ex. `<div>`). you can't return multiple element like this.

```
<>
    <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
</>
```

`<>` is shorthand for `<ReactFragment>`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSX code is finally converted to a JS code using Babel or other transpilers.

`<Text>` will be converted to something like `ReactDom.createElement('Text', {}, {});`

Given the way you have currently written your code, it will get compiled to a function which returns two function calls. That simply isn't possible.

Hence you can always return just one top level element. However, you are free to wrap as many elements as you want inside that top level element.

Answer (score 0):

when want to render multi-element it must be wrapped all element in on container 
look

```
<div>
    <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
</div>
```

or use React.fragment

```
 <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>

</React.Fragement>
```

or used
this sahpe

```
<>
<Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Text>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
</>
```